# "Стояла две кровати" или "стояло две кровати"?

Tags: согласование

Как правильно:

> В комнате стоял**о** две кровати

или

> В комнате стоял**а** две кровати.

И почему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможны такие варианты:

> В комнате стояло две кровати

и

> В комнате стояли две кровати

Ни один из этих вариантов не будет ошибкой, но выбор более подходящего по контексту варианта не всегда прост. Приведу правило (подробнее лучше прочитать [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/64-bolshinstvo)):

> **Согласование сказуемого с числительными**
>
> Имя числительное, в отличие от других имен (существительного и
>   прилагательного), лишено признаков числа. Иными словами, если
>   существительные могут иметь формы единственного и множественного числа
>   (книга – книги), то числительные не имеют таких форм (ср.: два,
>   пятеро, сто пятьдесят). По этой причине с числительным собственно
>   «согласование» сказуемого по форме числа принципиально невозможно.
>   Форма сказуемого единственного или множественного числа выбирается
>   говорящим произвольно. **При постановке сказуемого в ед. ч. прошедшего
>   времени сказуемое принимает форму среднего рода**: *пятьдесят человек
>   пришло на лекцию, в ДТП погибло два человека; открылось десять новых
>   магазинов* и т. п.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь множественное число, поэтому "стояли две кровати".

Comment: Ответ неверный, на всякий случай минусую, но только чтобы компенсировать поставленный кем-то плюс.

Comment: @grizzly  
"По муромской дороге    
стоялИ три сосны..."

Comment: @Michael_1812 Да, конечно. А что? Посмотрите, пожалуйста, мой ответ. Если там слишком коротко для понимания, пройдите по ссылке, там подробнее объясняется.